# Hyper-V Centos VM (VHDX) to ISO for Virtualizor VPS Deployments

Tags: centos, virtual-machines

I have an application that is installed on a customized version of CentOS 8 with various dependencies. I set this Virtual Machine up on my Windows laptop with Hyper-V.

Hyper-V uses VHDX files. The Virtual Machine provisioning software I am using (Virtualizor) requires an ISO file. I believe for this use case it needs to be bootable.

**Please see the expanded description below:**

My hope is to be able to create several instances of this virtual machine and put it on some powerful hardware. So, I got a dedicated server with a software called Softaculous Virtualizor so I could deploy several Virtual Private Servers with this custom OS image.

My research has not led me to a solution yet. I tried to use a tool called Mondo Rescue without success.

An alternative solution is to deploy a new CentOS Virtual Private Server with Virtualizor and customize it as needed again. Then I could duplicate that VPS. I would prefer to avoid having to re-configure the operating system to meet my needs by taking an ISO copy of my Hyper-V VM.

Comment: It sounds like Virtualizor is the wrong tool for this job. Consider using something else.